# Energy change as ball rolls down a curved ramp

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, energy-conservation, potential-energy

> At the top of the ramp, the ball has gravitational potential energy. As the ball rolls down the ramp, the potential energy converts to kinetic energy. Due to friction, some energy is also converted to thermal energy. The ramp curves upwards at the bottom. So the ball then moves upwards. So the kinetic energy turns back to potential energy. The final height is less that initial height. To describe this change, which option is most accurate:
>
> 1. potential → kinetic → potential + thermal
> 2. potential → kinetic + thermal → potential + thermal

My guess is 1, l know that friction is caused due to motion, so kinetic energy should be converting to thermal, and thus kinetic is converted to potential and thermal at the end of the experiment.

But I think 2 could also be correct as friction is caused simultaneously as potential is converted to kinetic, and after maximum potential energy is converted, the kinetic starts to convert back to potential, also simultaneously producing heat.

I understand the topic, but I am not sure how to express on paper. Please give an answer and explain why the other is wrong.

Comment: Energy is lost to heat going down and going back up. (Answer 2)

Comment: @R.W. Bird no thermal energy will be produced because the ball is rolling.

Comment: @Unique In any real situation heat is produced due to rolling friction as I explained to you below because  no deformation is perfectly elastic. You now have three separate contributors trying to tell you this. What  is it that you don't understand about rolling friction?

Comment: The fact that the final height is less than the initial indicates that energy is lost to some kind of friction, air or rolling. This would occur going down as well as back up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume > means “goes to” not “greater than”.

Not sure what the sequence is intended to describe but on the way down PE is simultaneously converted to  KE and heat dissipated by friction. At the bottom of the path the kinetic energy will be

$$KE_{bottom} = PE_{start}-Q_1$$

Where $Q_1$ = energy dissipated in the environment in the form of friction heating on the way down.

At the end on the way up

$$PE_{end} = KE_{bottom}-Q_2$$

Where $Q_{2}$ = energy dissipated in the environment in the form of friction heating on the way up.

For overall conservation of energy we have

$$PE_{end}=PE_{start}-(Q_{1}+Q_{2})$$

So I think option 2 is most accurate qualitatively realizing PE at the end is less than PE at the start. Also, friction heat on the way up is less than on the way down assuming the ramp is symmetrical about the bottom since friction work depends on the length of the path.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, Your post really helped!!

Comment: @FieryRMS You are welcome

Comment: @FieryRMS I'm glad it helped, but did it acceptably answer your question?

Comment: @Bob D why thermal energy would be produced?Friction will do zero work as it is the case of pure rolling!

Comment: @Unique The OP stated that rolling friction is involved. Are you aware there is such a thing as rolling friction or rolling resistance? It is the result of non elastic behavior which means not all of the energy involved with deformation of a wheel is recovered. Think about the tire on the wheel of a car. When the tire is in contact with the road the rubber compresses (squeezes),  and then when the contact ends it decompresses (un squeezes). The deformation is not purely elastic and therefore some heat is generated to do internal friction. This is different than sliding  friction.

Answer (score 0):

Friction is a force which opposes relative motion. In 1, it is given that the potential energy turns to kinetic fully, then the kinetic energy, then to potential and kinetic energy which is not the case. Reasoning is as follows,
Whenever some kinetic energy is produced, friction opposes it.(even in case I consider infinitesimal displacement, it produces a tiny amount of heat.) So, potential energy should be converted to kinetic and thermal enegry at the same time. Then, when it will start climbing up the curve, kinetic energy is converted to potential enegry and thermal too, because of the presence of friction. So, the answer should be 2.
[I considered it to be non pure rolling as in pure rolling, no heat enegry is produced]

Comment: I think you might want to differentiate "pure rolling"  from "ideal rolling". Pure rolling  does not involve sliding and therefore does not involve sliding friction. But there still can be rolling friction, a.k.a rolling resistance due to non elastic deformation. "Ideal rolling" would imply perfectly elastic behavior and would not involve rolling friction.